# Python rauth - do POST requests work?

Tags: python-2.7, rauth

I have an application that uses python2.7 and rauth to communicate with the etrade api.

Getting the etrade verification token and setting up an authorized session works, and I can successfully execute GET accesses like this:

```
url = 'https://etwssandbox.etrade.com/accounts/sandbox/rest/accountlist.json'
response  = session.get(url, params = {'format': 'json'}, header_auth=True)
```

I haven't had any success with POST accesses at all, and despite much searching have yet to find an example that shows the use of post with rauth. I am trying:

```
url = 'https://etwssandbox.etrade.com/order/sandbox/rest/placeequityorder'

id = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%y%m%d%H%M')+ticker

payload = {
    "PlaceEquityOrder": {
        "-xmlns": "http://order.etws.etrade.com",
        "EquityOrderRequest": {
            "accountId": account,
            "clientOrderId": id,
            "limitPrice": "",
            "quantity": qty,
            "symbol": ticker,
            "orderAction": "BUY",
            "priceType": "MARKET",
            "marketSession": "REGULAR",
            "orderTerm": "GOOD_FOR_DAY"
        }
    }
}

response = session.post(url, payload, header_auth=True)
```

and the response I get from etrade is:

```
{  
   'cookies':<RequestsCookieJar   [  

   ]   >,
   '_content':'<Error>\n  <message>oauth_problem=signature_invalid</message>\n</Error>',
   'headers':{  
      'Content-Length':'69',
      'Expires':'Sat, 21 May 1995 12:00:00 GMT',
      'Keep-Alive':'timeout=60, max=400',
      'apiServerName':'20w44m3',
      'Connection':'Keep-Alive',
      'Pragma':'no-cache',
      'Cache-Control':'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
      'Date':'Wed, 17 May 2017 15:16:42 GMT',
      'Server':'Apache',
      'WWW-Authenticate':'OAuth realm=https://etws.etrade.com/,oauth_problem=signature_invalid'
   },
   'url':   u'https://etwssandbox.etrade.com/order/sandbox/rest/placeequityorder',
   'status_code':401,
   '_content_consumed':True,
   'encoding':None,
   'request':<PreparedRequest   [  
      POST
   ]   >,
   'connection':<requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter object at 0x7f3187f71790>,
   'elapsed':datetime.timedelta(0,
   0,
   149246   ),
   'raw':<requests.packages.urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x7f3186c7ab90>,
   'reason':'Unauthorized',
   'history':[  

   ]
}
```

I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong with the POST request, but is it possible that the rauth library isn't adding the authentication stuff to POST requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I didn't get to the bottom of the failing rauth POST requests, but I found an alternative solution.

I'm using the etrade access functions from etradePythonApi (https://github.com/haualan/etradePythonAPI/blob/master/etradepy.py), with the exception that I stripped out the splinter & pyvirtualdisplay code that was attempting to scrape/insert login details into the etrade verification page, and instead replaced it with the oob code from ethann's answer on this page: [Getting an oauth request token from etrade in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28579489/getting-an-oauth-request-token-from-etrade-in-python/28685383#28685383)

Everything is working nicely using requests directly rather than going via the rauth wrapper, which seems to confirm that POST requests are not getting the Oauth blessing in rauth.

**Update:** I have made my program available for others to use & adapt at https://github.com/geekbrit/EtradeHotKeys